# How to spread points in boxplot in R?

Tags: r, boxplot

I am working on data distribution which has following follwing points.

input<-read.table("infile",header=TRUE,sep="\t")

table(input)

```
0.786333        1  1.04453  1.06159  1.33277  1.53607  2.25893 
  49      938        1        1       36       16      166
```

if i plot box plot for it, i get single line for lowest datum, highest datum and median.

boxplot(input)

[image]

Is there any way to distribute points by normalization so that can have better boxplot with distinct boundary for lowest datum, highest datum and median?

Comment: Boxplot is complety wrong approach given your data, which have two clear peaks and only few other values. What do you really want to show with your figure?

Comment: I m planning to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927473/how-to-plot-bar-plot-in-parallel-to-horizontal-to-box-plot-with-fraction-of-area

Comment: Well as you can see from your figure, your data does not suit for that kind of plot.

Answer (score 2):

You clearly have a biomodal distribution, I don't think a boxplot is a useful summary here

A density plot is more useful

```
plot(density(zz))
```

[image]

You could also consider a *violin plot* which is a bit of a mix between a kernel density plot and boxplot.

Using the `vioplot` package

```
 library(vioplot)
 violplot(zz)
```

Comment: But i need to classify them in category like we have 25%, 50% and 25% for boxplot. Can i do the same with density plot?

Comment: @user15662 you only have 7 unique values out of 1207 -- use those to create meaningful categories. That being said, the density plot clearly shows you could use a cutoff near 1.5 for two categories.

Comment: Actually i need to plot one barplot parallel to boxplot with something (high, medium, low). zz<-rnorm(1:1000)
 boxplot(zz), where box width(50%) is medium and on other side it is low(25%) and high(25%). I don't think i can do this with vioplot.